Auxiliary Particles Green's Function Factoring - Just Tensor Algebra Calculation and Consequences?
I have a question regarding the single-particles Green's Function in Imaginary time $\tau$ for a physical fermion $c^\dagger$ expressed by the quasi-particles auxiliary fields
$$ c^\dagger_{i, \sigma} = f^\dagger_{i,\sigma} e^{-i \theta_i} = f^\dagger_{i,\sigma} X_i^\dagger$$
which are known as the spinon $f$ and rotor $e^{-i\theta_i}$, which is expressed by the complex bosonic field $X$. They are linked by a constraint ensuring that only physical states are considered, but this doesn't matter here.
For information and applications please see https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.66.165111.
Regarding the Green's function $$\mathcal{G}_{ij}(\tau) = -\langle \mathcal{T}_\tau c_i(\tau)c_j^\dagger(0)\rangle,$$ where $\mathcal{T}$ is the time ordering operator, which will be simplified to a Heaviside function as we focus on $\tau > 0$.
In the introductory paper on the matter by Florens and Georges, as given above, it is stated that the Green's function in imaginary time factors as
$$\mathcal{G}_{ij}(\tau) = G^f_{ij}(\tau)G^X_{ij}(\tau).$$
(I believe there is an additional minus for $\tau$ in $G^X$, but this should be just a consequence of the sign in the exponential when factoring, right?)
I want to know if this follows directly from the tensor product algebra, especially based on the consideration that
$$\mathrm{Tr}(A \otimes B) = \mathrm{Tr}(A)\mathrm{Tr}(B),$$
or if there are more arguments for auxiliary particles necessary.
For a more in-depth argument here is my argumentation:

The product property of tensor algebra leads to $e^{A \otimes I}= e^A \otimes I $
The writing above is just short for $c^\dagger f^\dagger \otimes X^\dagger$
The Hamiltonian factors also $\hat{H} = H_f \otimes I +I  \otimes H_X$
And the expectancy value is a thermal, or (grand)canonical ensemble
one: $\langle A \rangle = \mathrm{Tr}\rho A$ with $\rho = \frac{1}{Z}
e^{-\beta H}$ and $Z = \mathrm{Tr} e^{-\beta H} $
$$ \implies Z = \mathrm{Tr} \ e^{-\beta (H_f \otimes I +I  \otimes H_X)} = \mathrm{Tr} \left( e^{-\beta H_f} \otimes e^{-\beta  H_X} \right) = \mathrm{Tr} \left(e^{-\beta H_f} \right)\cdot \mathrm{Tr}\left(e^{-\beta  H_X}\right) = Z_f Z_X$$

Then I would argue that:
\begin{align}
\mathcal{G} &= -\theta(\tau)\langle c(\tau)c^\dagger(0) \rangle \\ 
&= -\theta(\tau) \frac{1}{{Z_f Z_X}} \mathrm{Tr} \big( (e^{-\beta H_f} \otimes e^{-\beta H_X}) \cdot (f(\tau) \otimes X(\tau) ) ( f^\dagger(0) \otimes X^\dagger(0)) \big) \\ 
&= -\theta^2(\tau) \frac{1}{Z_f Z_X} \mathrm{Tr} \big(e^{-\beta H_f} f(\tau) f^\dagger(0)\big) \cdot \mathrm{Tr} \big(e^{-\beta H_X} X(\tau) X^\dagger(0) \big) \\ 
&= \left(-\theta(\tau) \frac{1}{Z_f} \mathrm{Tr} \big(e^{-\beta H_f} f(\tau) f^\dagger(0)\big) \right) 
\left(\theta(\tau) \frac{1}{Z_X} \mathrm{Tr} \big(e^{-\beta H_X} X(\tau) X^\dagger(0)\big) \right) \\ 
&= G_f \cdot G_X
\end{align}
Here I use the indexed Hamiltonian and Partition functions referring to the part given by the spinon and rotor respectively.
We should note a sign difference between $f$ and $X$ in the last step.
Follow-up question, does this mean that the Dyson Equations are given by
$$G_f = (G_{f,0}^{-1} - \Sigma_f)^{-1}$$
$$G_X = (G_{X,0}^{-1} + \Sigma_X)^{-1}$$
or has the change in the sign for the definition of the Green's function $G^X_{ij} = +\langle \mathcal{T}_\tau X_i(\tau) X_j^\dagger(0) \rangle$ no influence on the Dyson equation?
Final follow-up question, is $$\mathcal{G}_{ij}(\tau>0) = -\theta(\tau)\langle c_i(\tau)c_j^\dagger(0)\rangle \overset{i\neq j}{=} +\theta(\tau)\langle c_j^\dagger(0) c_i(\tau)\rangle $$ by the fermionic anticommutation relations, or am I missing something here?
